# What is the name for the space of distributions over smooth compactly supported test functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

Is there a generally accepted name for the space of distributions over smooth compactly supported test functions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I know that distributions over the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are called "tempered distributions," and distributions over $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ test functions are called "distributions with compact support."

I can't seem to find a name for the space $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean *continuous* compactly supported test functions?  Because the dual of that space is the space of Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sorry, should have said $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ test functions with compact support. Is there a name for the space of distributions defined on those test functions?

Comment: Those are usually just called "distributions." Here is a good  [overview](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/) of the different varieties of distributions.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah ok I get it. I forgot that tempered distributions and compactly supported Distributions are a subset of $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$. Thanks for the blog link too very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in comments:

> Those are usually just called "distributions." Here is a good [overview](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/) of the different varieties of distributions. Hope it helps. –  icurays1 Nov 20 '12 at 6:10